# POST array y guardarlo entero en campo

Tags: php

Tengo un formulario que recoge varias variables entre ellas 3 arrays... los envío por POST a operaciones.php para que las guarde pero no hay forma. He de decir que lo que quiero es guardar en el mismo campo todo el array, a ser posible separado con #. Es decir, tengo un campo instructores y quiero guardar todos los instructores en ese mismo campo separado por #.

**HTML**

```
<label>Implicados:</label>
<select id="framework_a" name="implicados_a[]" multiple class="form-control" >
<?php
$query = mysql_query("select * from padron order by id_padron asc")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){    ?>
<option value="<?php echo $row['id_padron'];?>"><?php echo $row['nombre'];?></option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

**OPERACIONES.PHP**

```
$investigados = implode("#", $_POST['investigados']);
```

y luego quiero insertar esa variable, entre otras, en una tabla

```
mysql_query("insert into atestados (num_atestado,investigados)
    values ('$num_atestado','$investigados')") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Aunque no me parece una buena idea lo que quieres hacer... ¿qué se supone que hay en `$_POST['investigados']`?  ¿No debería ser más bien: **`$investigados = implode("#", $_POST['implicados_a']);`** Y, dinos ¿qué problema o error tienes en concreto? ¿Qué **depuraciones** has hecho, empezando por `var_dump($_POST);` y cuáles son los resultados?

Comment: Realmente no sé como podría hacerlo de otra forma... la cuestión es que no guarda ningún dato, sin embargo le quito los arrays y guarda el registro. Lo que no quiero es tener en un mismo registro 10 campos de investigados por ejemplo.

Comment: En investigados están los IDS de cada uno de ellos que escojo con un select multiple en el form

Comment: Si el `select` es el que tiene `name="implicados_a[]"` debes hacer algo así: **`$investigados = implode("#", $_POST['implicados_a']);`** tú estás buscando en el POST un elemento con clave `investigados`, pero en el código no veo ningún elemento que tenga ese `name`. Haz un `var_dump($_POST);` y verás qué estructura tienen tus datos. Eso es lo primero que hay que hacer cuando tienes problemas: **depurar** los elementos problemáticos para revisarlos.

Comment: He corregido lo de implode pero sigue sin funcionar. var_dump($_POST); tampoco me da resultados. Investigaré un poco más a ver que puede ser...

Comment: Revisa el `action` del formulario, debe apuntar al archivo correcto y a la ruta correcta. Si no te sale aunque sea `null` al poner el `var_dump` puede que haya un error en el formulario o que no esté apuntando al archivo correcto. No has puesto el formulario completo en la pregunta, por tanto no se puede verificar desde aquí.

Comment: Gracias @A.Cedano. En cuanto lo solucione os lo hago saber!

Comment: Lo siento... me faltaba una coma de separación entre dos campos dentro del insert. Siento las molestias... lo que investigaré es cómo hacerlo de otra manera que no sea la de guardar todo el array en un campo. Gracias!